# Eclipse can't find pom: Resource out of sync error?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have some problems with Eclipse. When I "Run" i see the following error message.?

> ```
> File not found:...\pom.properties.
> File not found: C:\Users..\pom.xml.
> Resource is out of sync with the file system 
> (error repeated for every class of the project)
> ```

I'm trying to ripristinate the pom path, can anybody give me some advice about how ripristinate the path?
(to fix the problem i also tried: Maven clean, Maven build, Maven instal or to update project, but i didn't resolve the problem)

The problem appeard when I connect visual studio code to Eclipse workspace ("i click on add a folder to the workspace" on VS code)

Comment: Try to press F5 with the project selected in the Project Explorer

Comment: Thanks a lot, i tried, something happend, the red X mark on the project disappears, buit if i go on the project properties  --> java build path i can see that the project path is still missing

Comment: the metadata for the eclipse project is broken... little that I can do without a look

Comment: i Know, by the way thaks a lot for writing! :)

Comment: Do you mean recreate or restore?  How did you create the POM file in the first place?

Comment: Problem solved! Ihad to press F5 on the project and  after unistall JDK (my version wasn't the correct version)

Answer (score 1):

The file was  modified  by another process, the cache is out of sync with the actual file, try refreshing.

Comment: hi!! The problem appeard when i connect visual studio code to Eclipse workspace ("i click on add a folder to the workspace" on VS code)

Comment: Yup ... so VSC has changed some files behind the back of Eclipse. Eclipse is confused.

Comment: i was more confused than eclipse ahahahah by the way problem solved! i had to press F5 on the project and unistall JDK (my version wasn't the correct version)